# How to use XML file stored at different location inside XSL file

Tags: xslt

I have below XML file stored at D:\test

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Your comments.-->
<root>
<Sample name="pal">
<Name>pal</Name>
<Age>24</Age>
<Job>software</Job>
</Sample>
</root>
```

I am trying to use it in below XSL file at D:\test\test1\test2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="root/sample">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="Name" /></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="Age" /></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am not able to get the required result.

Comment: Can someone help on the issue?

Comment: Help much appriciated